# How to upgrade units in Nexus wars?

Tags: starcraft-2

I couldn't find the building/command to upgrade armor/attack of my units. Google is no help either. The other guys can do it, and when I ask them how to do it on ally chat, they just ignore me/kick me from the lobby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrades are purchased at the 'Upgrades and Heroes' building, with the appearance of the campaign 'Merc Compound'. The building hotkey is <kbd>E</kbd>, next to the Blink ability, as shown in the image below. [Relevant Source](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/sc2-maps/306535-nexus-wars-comprehensive-strategy-guide)

[image]

When selecting the building there are four buttons for heroes. The final three buttons are to access the upgrades. The hotkeys for Terran, Zerg and Protoss technologies are <kbd>Z</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>, and <kbd>C</kbd>, respectively. Selecting these buttons opens menu for that race's upgrades.

[image]

For example, after pressing <kbd>Z</kbd>, you will see the Terran upgrades visible below.

[image]

Comment: The thing is, when I click on this building, I only see Hero units and a few add-on upgrades (like Reaper's Nitro boost). I see no Armour/Attack upgrades. Can you show me the screenshot where you these armour/attack upgrades after you build the Merc compound?

Comment: @AmanSingh The 'Reaper' upgrade actually opens the screen for Terran upgrades, I have expanded my answer in this regard.